# How to return a set of objects in a collection which match a set of fields in another collection with .find() in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I've been trying to learn how to use the Meteor platform and very new to it all.  I've found that what I thought would be a simple task seems very difficult to implement in the meteor platform.  I'm simply trying to display Recipes which contain the matching fields of the 'checked' ingredients.

I have two sets of collections:
- Vegetables contains 'ingredients' as a field and 'checked' as a (boolean) field.
- Recipes contains 'ingredients' as a field as well as 'description' and 'name'

I am trying to return a find which shows all of the recipes that contain the ingredients which are checked in the Vegetables objects.

What I've found is I can't directly embed a collection inside a .find: the error says "too much recursion".  I think this would simply be:

```
Recipes.find(vegetables.find({'checked': true}, {fields: {_id: 0, ingredients: 1}}))
```

If only it were that easy... what I've done is in the submit button event I do the following:

```
Session.set('SelectedVeg', vegetables.find({'checked': true}, {fields: {_id: 0, ingredients: 1}}).fetch());
Session.set('count', vegetables.find({'checked': true}, {fields: {_id: 0, ingredients: 1}}).count());
```

Then in the function to display recipes:

```
'recipe': function () {
  var length = Session.get('count');
  FoundRecipes = Recipes.find(Session.get('SelectedVeg')[0]).fetch();
  return FoundRecipes;
}
```

I've found I have to use the [0] after the Session.get('SelectedVeg') in order to get any results.  This works, but it only searched the first object that has 'checked': true in the vegetables collection.  I tried a for loop but with no luck (can't seem to add more info to 'FoundRecipes' or use it as an array). I need it to return all of the recipes that are found which contain ANY of the vegetables selected.  I've been trying many different ways of solving the problem but nothing is working... Gurus of Meteor, please help!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem here is the data structure of `selectedVeg`

Based on some information you've provided, I'm going to assume that the `vegetables.ingredients` field is a flat value (eg, not an array). If `ingredients` is an array, let me know and I'll update the answer.

### Problem

The query

```
vegetables.find({'checked': true}, {fields: {_id: 0, ingredients: 1}}).fetch();
```

would return

```
[
  {ingredients: a},
  {ingredients: b},
  {ingredients: c},
  // ...
  {ingredients: z}
]
```

Thus, the query:

```
FoundRecipes = Recipes.find(Session.get('selectedVeg')[0]).fetch()
```

Would only get `{ingredients: a}` as the selector - and only return limited results.

### Solution

Use underscore to change the value stored in `selectedVeg`

```
// get your data as normal
var selectedVeg = vegetables.find({
  'checked': true
}, {
   fields: { 
     ingredients: 1
   }
});
// then convert [{ingredients: x}, ... ] -> [x, y, z]
selectedVeg = _.pluck(selectedVeg.fetch(), 'ingredients');
// set session value as normal
Session.set('selectedVeg', selectedVeg);
Session.set('count', selectedVeg.length);
```

Then, when you try to find recipes, change the query to use the `$in` operator

```
FoundRecipes = Recipes.find({
 ingredients: {
   $in: Session.get('selectedVeg')
 }
}).fetch()
```

Comment: I think you could be right about the data types.  I'm having trouble aligning data types of the query and the item being queried. When I made the Ingredients, they are just stored as individual items in the collection, with the fields 'ingredients' and 'checked'.  The Recipes collection stores the ingredients as an array (I wasn't quite sure how to make a nested collection for them) as follows: 

Recipes.insert({'ingredients': ['Brussel Sprouts', 'Onions', 'Garlic'], 'name': 'Roasted Brussel Sprouts', 'description': 'Seared Brussel Sprouts w....', 'instructions': 'Blah...'});

Comment: The webconsole now tells me "Type Error: SelectedVeg is undefined" and the query is still not working.  Perhaps its because the ingredients in the Recipes collection are stored as an array?

Comment: Hi Sam. the error you've pasted has `SelectedVeg` with a capital `S` - is it possible you've mis-typed one of the variable names?

Comment: No, I checked and the variable I used throughout was SelectedVeg. However the error references the line with the _.pluck command.  Perhaps it is a problem with underscore?  I'm not too familiar with underscore and I tried to install it (with terminal in ubuntu).  Not sure if everything went correctly.

Comment: It's got to be something else - what are you editing your project with? I find https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/ really awesome (there's a free trial for a month) - it usually finds a bunch of errors you don't see in other editors

Answer (score 0):

With Nathan M's help, I managed to find a solution to the problem. I finally found that using the _.pluck command from underscore solved the issue.

with the submit button here is the code:

```
  Template.button.events({
    "click .submit": function () {
      Session.set('PossibleRecipes', true);  //Sets to change helper to display possible recipes page.
      selectedVeg = _.pluck(vegetables.find({'checked': true}).fetch(), 'ingredients');
      Session.set('SelectedVeg', selectedVeg);
    }
  });
```

and in the helpers for the Possible Recipes page I have the following:

```
  Template.PosRec.helpers({
    'visiblePR': function () {
      if (Session.get('PossibleRecipes') == true) {
        return "visible"
      }
      else return "hidden"
    },
    'recipe': function () {
      FoundRecipes = Recipes.find({ingredients: {$in: Session.get('SelectedVeg')}}).fetch();
      return FoundRecipes;
    }
  });
```

The final step was going straight to using the _.pluck on the vegetables collection straight instead of on a session.  This returns an array of the checked vegetables.  Then with the helper 'recipe' I return FoundRecipes, which finds the corresponding Recipes that have the ingredients in the SelectedVeg array.